# How to use two key words inside else statement inside another keyword

Tags: robotframework

I have a keyword that takes one string parameter and one collection
I would like to change extend it like this:
Depends on what value will be in string parameter inside this keyword will run another keywords. So far I’m have something like this but cannot get the syntax right. String parameter and collection will be passed to those different keywords

```
I pick Item in picker
[Arguments]    ${SOMEVALUE}    @{GROUPS}
${TYPE}=    Set Variable    ${SOMEVALUE}
Run Keyword If    '${TYPE} ' == ‘1’    I pick item in 
ELSE IF
Run Keyword If    '${TYPE} ' == ‘2’    I pick something else
```

Both of those additional keywords taking SOMEVALUE and GROUPS as parameters just do different stuff with them. Problem is using step I pick Item in picker with 1 as parameter does not invokes I pick item in step

Comment: The syntax for using `ELSE IF` on multiple lines is given in the [keyword documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) - you have to put triple dots (`...`) at the start of the line. That by the way is the way of breaking up long arguments list on multiple lines in RF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have additional space between closing bracket `${TYPE}` and `'`.

If I understand you correctly you don't need `ELSE IF`. Two `Run Keyword If` with different expressions to evaluate would be enough.

Comment: Agreed on both accounts, the extra space b/n `${TYPE} ` and the ', and that this can be solved with just couple `Run Keyword If`, with no `ELSE IF` branch; well deserved upvote :). @verigo448 if you're reading this comment, the syntax for the else braches is given as an example in the keyword documentation.